# Resolve a viewmodel with MvvmCross 6.0

Tags: android, xamarin, fragment, inversion-of-control, mvvmcross

I have the following scenario:

On an Android tablet device, I have the screen split in 3. From left to right: menu -> list fragment (IMasterViewModel) -> detail fragment (IDetailViewModel).
Click item in the menu, show list, click item in list, show detail.

When I click on an item in the menu, I want to close all instance of type IMaster and IDetail viewmodel. Is there a way, using Mvx.Resolve, maybe, to find all viewmodel instances implementing these interfaces and close them?

Thank you.

Comment: I wouldn't do that, because in that case you would need to register those ViewModels as singletons, otherwise you would get new instances of them every time you resolve them. Your presenter should know about what is shown where, in here you could decide what to close based on your own conditions.

Comment: @Cheesebaron: you're perfectly right, that's how I ended up doing it. Thank you!